# Jquery shows image for few seconds then hides

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to use jquery to display an image when a button is clicked. It displays the image but then the page refreshes and the image is gone. I am pretty sure the issue is that when my button is clicked it does the form.submit which refreshes the page, but I need that because I am updating my dropdown list values from the hidden text box where the text of the button is being pasted (the page refreshes so the user does not have to hit enter, it does it automatically for them). I am was wondering how I can get it to do both so that when the button clicks it shows the image and page refreshes and the image is still there.

Here are the two versions of my function i Have tried and have not worked:

```
function moveText(text)
{
     document.getElementById("result").value=text;
}
function showImage() 
{
     $("#loadingImage").show();
     return false();
}
```

and the other one:

```
function moveText(text)
{
     document.getElementById("result").value=text;
}                            
function showImage(event) 
{
     $("#loadingImage").show();
     event.preventDefault();
}
```

Additional info:

Here is my button code:

```
  <input name="Failure Analysis Lab" 
   style="white-space:normal; width: 272px; height: 30px;" 
   onclick="moveText(this.name);showImage();
   form1.submit(); " type="button" 
   value="7QKD Failure Analysis Lab" />
```

Comment: Is your back-end language PHP, JSP, ASP.Net ?

Comment: the back-end language is asp.net

Comment: If you want to submit the form but avoid reloading the page, you should use AJAX.

Comment: To us to better understand the situation, post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.com).

Comment: I am a bit confused as to why this post was down voted?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add `return false` to your `onClick` event and remove the form submit.:

```
onclick="moveText(this.name);showImage(); return false;"
```

This will keep the postback from occurring.

Comment: But asker says that he needs to submit the form